# contentsof:url loads url content of a truncated URL

Tags: swift, url, wkwebview

When I use **contentsof:url** it truncates the url before retrieving the content, resulting in different html content than the displayed in the WKWebView.

For example

> contents = try String(contentsOf: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00BECJ4R8/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1531620716&sr=8-1-spons&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=cole+haan&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BECJ4R8))

returns the contents of this page: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00BECJ4R8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BECJ4R8)

Why is this happening? Is there an alternative method that allow you to read the content of the actual URL not the truncated URL?

Any advice if very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `String(contentsOf:)` to load a website. You should use the URL Loading System for this work then passing that object back to your `webView.load(_:)` method in `viewDidLoad()`

```
 let urlString = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00BECJ4R8/?tag=stackoverflow17-20"
 // URL construct may fail in case of the String not being a properly formatted URL, so unwrap it. 
 if let url = URL(string: urlString) { 
   // Create a URLRequest instance with the new url.
   let request = URLRequest(url: url) 
   // Load the request.  
   webView.load(request)
 }
```

Comment: SirCJ I am not loading the website via String(contentsOf:) I am trying to analyze the contents of a site that was in fact previously loaded with URLRequest, but the content obtained with String(contentsOf:) is different than the content displayed on the WKWebView. It appears that String(contentsOf) gets the content of the truncated URL not the complete URL that was assigned.